# About MKP Capacitors for Inverter Welding Machine

Tags: capacitor, inverter

I need your help with capacitors...

I'm restoring a 160A inverter welding machine, model Fimer X164.
One of the capacitors has cracked and I need tochange that..

Information about the capacitor on the board (i.e. exploded):

**PILKOR 10nF 300V-Y2 PCY2 130 MKP**

I can't find an identical capacitor but find similar values.

**I have**

**1- 10 n K 400 RIFA 404 FVN**

**2- RIFA 271 Y 522 250V MP**

**Can I use capacitor 1? Or what do you suggest as a replacement for this capacitor?**

[image]

Comment: what circuit currents do you expect?

Comment: What AC supply voltage does this machine use?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Welding Machine works with 220V - value of old and exploded capacitor is 300V..

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Machine works with 220 V

Comment: The second isn't 10nF, but 270.

Comment: You must use Y2 at the very least and preferably Y1 and the same value! If you don't have Y-rating and the capacitor fails again, it will pose a real risk of killing you or anyoen touching the welder.

Answer (score 8):

### Don't gamble your life over saving a couple of bucks!

The capacitor that exploded was not any old capacitor -- it is a special "Class Y" capacitor that's designed not to ever fail as a short circuit, which is ***extremely important*** because Class Y capacitors are used between things at mains voltage (no touchy!) and things you can touch.  If a regular capacitor like Capacitor 1 was used instead, it could short out when it failed, causing your welder to turn into a people-zapper.  Capacitor 2 appears to be of the correct *type* (Class Y) and voltage rating, but of the wrong value (270pF?) and probably won't be as effective at its job as the exploded capacitor was.

Get a 10nF, 250VAC Y2 capacitor from a *reputable* distributor (DigiKey, Mouser, Newark/Farnell, TME, RS/Allied, Future, and Arrow are the ones I know of -- it will not be China-cheap, but penny-wise is pound-foolish with life-safety-critical components like these) and install it in place of the blown-up cap.  (One way to determine if something's a proper safety rated capacitor is to look for test lab marks, such as UL, CSA, or the VDE mark seen on Capacitor 2 in your picture.)

Comment: Thank you very much for that important informations.. I dont think change capacitor before ask this place.. 

I should change only Y type? Or Can it be X type?

And last question: Old capacitor is 300V.. Can I use 250V or over 300V?

Thank you a lot of...

Comment: You must match the Y-rating. Some caps are rated for both X and Y applications, which is fine, but your replacement still must meet Y2.

Comment: You need a Y2 or Y1 capacitor (some caps are dual rated X1Y1 or X1Y2, they are fine.  Just don't get anything that's say X1 or X2 without the Y).  Also, 250VAC Y capacitors are fine in a 220VAC appliance -- X/Y capacitors are rated by their nominal working voltage.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank you very much dear.. They're very important info's.. Sorry for lot of questions but, I can't find 10nF.. Can I use 22nF for this application? (Inverter Welding Machine 220V)

Comment: @byzskl01 two 22nF in series will do in a pinch

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That's good idea I'll do that.. 
I find WIMA MKP 10 0.01 630-400 cap. 

I'll add photo of that. Should I use two series 22nF(RIFA) or WIMA MKP 10 0.01 ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd8UT.jpg @ThreePhaseEel Can I use this one?

Comment: @byzskl01 -- can you stop grabbing caps from the junkbox and *order the correct part in*? (as to the two RIFA caps, I don't know enough from here to say if they'll be OK for you)  You know, if you do it wrong now, you just might not ever get the chance to do it over...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That cap (Wima) was from other  Fimer welding machine.. I'll change old cap with two series 22nF RIFA Y 250v Cap ? That is OK? Thx for all answers dear

Comment: @byzskl01 -- do the 22nF RIFAs have a VDE, UL, etal mark on them? (posting a photo of them would be even better :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I see VDE-S-N-D-ÖVE marks on cap. I'll add photo of RIFA.. I've two RIFA now.. If is not problem I'll connect two serie 22nF..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/esuBi.jpg

Comment: @byzskl Ah.  These will work, yes -- the part number misled me into believing they were 270pF at first

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel They are each 22nF.. Write on top.. I connected series two 22nF RIFA on board. I didn't test yet but I trust your informations. Thank you very much for all answers.. Sorry for give tiredness..