# Change Pilkor MKP 10nF with WIMA MKP 10 10nF Capacitor

Tags: capacitor

**I need your help with capacitors...**

I'm restoring a 160A inverter welding machine, model Fimer X164. One of the capacitors has cracked and I need tochange that..

Information about the capacitor on the board (i.e. exploded):

**PILKOR 10nF 300V-Y2 PCY2 130 MKP**

I can't find an identical capacitor but find similar values.

I have

**1- WIMA MKP 10 10nF 400 630**

Can I use capacitor? Or what do you suggest as a replacement for this capacitor?

[image]

THANK YOU FOR ALL Answers other question:
[About MKP Capacitors for Inverter Welding Machine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/273309/about-mkp-capacitors-for-inverter-welding-machine)

Comment: Where on this planet are you anyhow?

Answer (score 0):

### Second verse, same as the first!  Your life is worth more than a few dollars saved on a junk-box capacitor!!!

Order in the proper Class Y (10nF/250VAC) safety rated capacitor, install it, and be done with it.  Sure, it might cost a few bucks, and a few more bucks to ship, but consider it an investment in *peace of mind* that your welder won't turn around and zap you some day!